# Python - Dataframe - Matplotly - KeyError: "None of [Int64Index / Datetime...] in the [Columns]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my very question in stackoverflow even though I am used to looking for solutions when I am stuck.
However, today, I am really stuck and I do not know how to handle the situation.

In a nutshell, I wrote a script which collect the price of Bitcoins and store it in a mySQL DB. Another python script goes to the DB to collect the data and I would like to generate a chart (line) using the matplotlib library.

I wanted to create a graph based on the datetime, using the following code

```
        sql = "SELECT * FROM t_btc_2 WHERE id_btc >= 3800;"
        mycursor.execute(sql)
        table_rows = mycursor.fetchall()
        df = pd.DataFrame(table_rows)
        mycursor.close()
        df.rename(columns={0: 'id_BTC', 1:'Date_and_Time', 2:'BTC_Value'}, inplace=True)
        ax = plt.gca()
        df.plot(kind='line', x=df['Date_and_Time'], y='BTC_Value', color='red', ax=ax)
        df.plot()
        plt.show()
```

But I get the following error:

```
KeyError: "None of [DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-26 22:08:44', '2020-01-26 22:08:55',\n               '2020-01-26 22:09:05', '2020-01-26 22:09:15',\n
     '2020-01-26 22:09:27', '2020-01-26 22:09:37',\n               '2020-01-26 22:09:45', '2020-01-26 22:09:57',\n               '2020-01-26 22:10:09', '2020-01-26 22:10:19',\n               '2020-01-26 22:10:28', '2020-01-26 22:10:38',\n               '2020-01-26 22:10:49', '2020-01-26 22:11:00',\n        
       '2020-01-26 22:11:08', '2020-01-26 22:11:18',\n               '2020-01-26 22:11:29', '2020-01-26 22:11:41',\n               '2020-01-26 22:11:51', 
'2020-01-26 22:12:02',\n               '2020-01-26 22:12:12', '2020-01-26 22:12:21',\n               '2020-01-26 22:12:31', '2020-01-26 22:12:42',\n      
         '2020-01-26 22:12:52', '2020-01-26 22:13:03',\n               '2020-01-26 22:13:13', '2020-01-26 22:13:23',\n               '2020-01-26 22:13:35', '2020-01-26 22:13:45',\n               '2020-01-26 22:13:56', '2020-01-26 22:14:06',\n               '2020-01-26 22:14:17', '2020-01-26 22:14:27',\n    
           '2020-01-26 22:14:36', '2020-01-26 22:14:49',\n               '2020-01-26 22:14:57', '2020-01-26 22:15:10',\n               '2020-01-26 22:15:19'],\n              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)] are in the [columns]"
```

I tried based on the primary key, with the following code:

```
        sql = "SELECT * FROM t_btc_2 WHERE id_btc >= 3800;"
        mycursor.execute(sql)
        table_rows = mycursor.fetchall()
        df = pd.DataFrame(table_rows)
        mycursor.close()
        df.rename(columns={0: 'id_BTC', 1:'Date_and_Time', 2:'BTC_Value'}, inplace=True)
        ax = plt.gca()
        df.plot(kind='line', x=df['id_BTC'], y='BTC_Value', color='red', ax=ax)
        df.plot()
        plt.show()
```

I got the following error:

```
KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([3800, 3801, 3802, 3803, 3804, 3805, 3806, 3807, 3808, 3809, 3810,\n            3811, 3812, 3813, 3814, 3815, 3816, 3817, 3818, 3819, 3820, 3821,\n            3822, 3823, 3824, 3825, 3826, 3827, 3828, 3829, 3830, 3831, 3832,\n            3833, 3834, 3835, 3836, 3837, 3838],\n 
          dtype='int64')] are in the [columns]"
```

The result of my SQL query provides the following result:

```
    id_BTC       Date_and_Time BTC_Value
0     3800 2020-01-26 22:08:44   8636.96
1     3801 2020-01-26 22:08:55   8636.96
2     3802 2020-01-26 22:09:05   8626.76
3     3803 2020-01-26 22:09:15   8637.24
4     3804 2020-01-26 22:09:27   8626.77
5     3805 2020-01-26 22:09:37   8637.24
6     3806 2020-01-26 22:09:45   8637.24
7     3807 2020-01-26 22:09:57   8634.99
8     3808 2020-01-26 22:10:09   8634.99
9     3809 2020-01-26 22:10:19   8634.15
10    3810 2020-01-26 22:10:28   8634.15
11    3811 2020-01-26 22:10:38   8635.00
12    3812 2020-01-26 22:10:49   8635.00
13    3813 2020-01-26 22:11:00   8635.00
14    3814 2020-01-26 22:11:08   8634.99
15    3815 2020-01-26 22:11:18   8625.11
16    3816 2020-01-26 22:11:29   8625.10
17    3817 2020-01-26 22:11:41   8634.99
18    3818 2020-01-26 22:11:51   8634.99
19    3819 2020-01-26 22:12:02   8625.10
20    3820 2020-01-26 22:12:12   8620.58
21    3821 2020-01-26 22:12:21   8633.80
22    3822 2020-01-26 22:12:31   8633.80
23    3823 2020-01-26 22:12:42   8633.80
24    3824 2020-01-26 22:12:52   8619.37
25    3825 2020-01-26 22:13:03   8619.37
26    3826 2020-01-26 22:13:13   8619.37
27    3827 2020-01-26 22:13:23   8631.41
28    3828 2020-01-26 22:13:35   8617.98
29    3829 2020-01-26 22:13:45   8617.98
30    3830 2020-01-26 22:13:56   8617.78
31    3831 2020-01-26 22:14:06   8611.47
32    3832 2020-01-26 22:14:17   8611.47
33    3833 2020-01-26 22:14:27   8611.47
34    3834 2020-01-26 22:14:36   8611.47
35    3835 2020-01-26 22:14:49   8618.88
36    3836 2020-01-26 22:14:57   8618.88
37    3837 2020-01-26 22:15:10   8614.13
38    3838 2020-01-26 22:15:19   8627.51
```

Is there a way to produce the expected chart? I want to get the evolution of the price during the requested timeframe.

Thank you for your time and help.

Tom

Answer (score 0):

The x, and y parameters of Pandas' plot() method require only the names of the columns as strings. In your code you are mixing the type of the objects you are passing to these parameters. There is also a redundant df.plot() in two places. The code below works. Please make sure you have converted the Date_and_Time column to a pandas datetime type using [pd.to_datetime()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create a toy data frame
rng = pd.date_range('1/5/2018 00:00', periods=5, freq='10M')
df = pd.DataFrame({'id_BTC': np.arange(5) + 3000,
                   'BTC_Value': np.random.randint(8000, 9000, 5),
                   'Date_and_Time': pd.date_range('20200101', periods=5,
                                                  freq='T')})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(kind='line', x='id_BTC', y='BTC_Value', color='red', ax=ax)
plt.show()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(kind='line', x='Date_and_Time', y='BTC_Value', color='red', ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi KRKirov, thank you very much for your answer which works perfectly fine. I have adapted your code to fit with my needs.

Comment: Yes, now I've tried to generate an animation with the data, I manage to get no error but... no line drawn... [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59975291/data-animation-matplotlib-python-no-line-drawn).